# Different hash code when piping "sha1sum" to "tar" output

Tags: pipe, tar, aix, hashsum

In AIX system (v 7.1) `sha1sum` is calculating different hash codes when its piped directly to the output of `tar` compared to when it reads a file.

What are the reasons for this ? Are there ways to workaround this and get the hash code directly from the `tar` piped output ?

*(In others systems like Debian and Ubuntu, piped `sha1sum` to `tar` output works well)*

```
folder=myfolder
tarfile=myfolder.tar

tar -cf $tarfile $folder && sha1sum $tarfile
fe2dcba2b25d4bbb35460309c8bb87a1d2514d7d  myfolder.tar

tar -cf $tarfile $folder && sha1sum $tarfile
fe2dcba2b25d4bbb35460309c8bb87a1d2514d7d  myfolder.tar

tar -cf - $folder > $tarfile && sha1sum $tarfile
fe2dcba2b25d4bbb35460309c8bb87a1d2514d7d  myfolder.tar

tar -cf - $folder > $tarfile && sha1sum $tarfile
fe2dcba2b25d4bbb35460309c8bb87a1d2514d7d  myfolder.tar

tar -cf - $folder | sha1sum
f1dd1a0c4e82dd5c441664869b656c7bce799270  -

tar -cf - $folder | sha1sum
f1dd1a0c4e82dd5c441664869b656c7bce799270  -
```

Comment: Test with `sha1sum` again but on a really tiny file (tarred) to make sure it's still behaving in the same way. Then replace `sha1sum` with `od` ("octal dump") and compare visually to figure out what the differences are.  I believe that there's also a `sha1` utility on AIX that you can try in place of GNU coreutil's `sha1sum`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: The issue looks to be with a sort of flushing of `tar` output. I tried these: `tar -cf - smallfile | wc -c` vs `tar -cf - smallfile > tarfile && wc -c tarfile`, and I got respectively: 4096 vs 10240. Where smallfile has a "hi" without newline. (btw, about 10K minimum output to tar only 2 bytes)

Comment: Try with another `tar` implementation, for example `gtar` (the one from the GNU people), if you have access to it.

Comment: appears that tar writes extra nulls when writing to a file vs stdout

Comment: look into the `-b` parameter; seems to affect the output here

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I tried `tar -cf - smallfile | cat > tarfile` and tarfile became with only 4096 bytes. Probably AIX tar is changing its behaviour according to stdout fd (file descriptor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that problem is the command `tar`. It has internal records made of a fixed number of 512 bytes blocks. The number of blocks per record can be set with the parameter `-b`.

Some implementations can adjust the amount of blocks automatically according to the file descriptor, if its a tape device, a regular file, or a pipe.

Fixing the amount of blocks with the `-b` parameter fixed the problem. Like as: `tar -b1 -cf - $folder | sha1sum`. But to match the default blocks predefined in the first two commands of the question I had to use `-b20` (10240 byte records is the default for archives stored in regular files):

```
$ tar -b20 -cf - $folder > $tarfile && sha1sum $tarfile
fe2dcba2b25d4bbb35460309c8bb87a1d2514d7d  myfolder.tar

$ tar -b20 -cf - $folder |sha1sum                      
fe2dcba2b25d4bbb35460309c8bb87a1d2514d7d
```